# Billing Information not saving at Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, database

When I fill in this form on checkout, It does not save
When I order something new, the fields are not filled in because its not saved.
I want to have the fields saved to the database in order to use those credentials.
Does anyone know how?

[image: The checkout form]

Comment: You want to save the address entered while (completing the) checkout into the My Account address book for later use?

Comment: YES!!! :) you understand me

Comment: In the default templates there is a checkbox present which is used for exactly this purpose. So you'll have to compare your form phtml with either f the original ones and update your theme's form it accordingly